# JS doesn't work after I include it?

Tags: javascript, php, include

I'm using a Google geolocation script to let users insert their adress.

I've created a single page (zoeken.php) where this script works. http://laurenz.be/winterhard/final/zoeken.php

Then I include it to my index.php

```
<?php
include 'zoeken.php'; 
?>
```

And when I visit the index.php the JS stopped working? 
http://laurenz.be/winterhard/final/
Then I get the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).geocomplete is not a function'

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm realy stuck on this one...

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** This is the file 'zoeken.php'

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="z-index:999;" >           

  <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="general-title">
 <h4>Titel1</h4>
 </div>
 <p>Opvultekst en intro. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi id leo at justo imperdiet elementum sit amet non mi. Curabitur turpis urna, faucibus eget sagittis eu, molestie eget turpis. Nam id leo in ligula semper molestie. Quisque vel pulvinar massa. Vivamus varius malesuada ex non congue. Aenean eget purus euismod, dignissim nulla at, blandit arcu.
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="lighter">  


    <form>
      <input id="geocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Type in an address" size="90" />
      <input id="find" type="button" value="find" />
    </form>


    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="logger.js"></script>
        <script src="overige.js"></script>






  </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please specify the content of zoeken.php file

Comment: My educated guess is the order in which the files are loaded. I think jQuery isn't fully loaded when you include `zoeken.php`. Please post more of the file in which you include `zoeken.php`

Comment: Append `script` tags to `head`

Comment: Looked at your source code, indeed place the script elements into your `head` or at the top of your `body`. At least `zoeken.php` should be included beneath those script elements.

Comment: Try removing the jquery script from `zoeken.php` and add it  inside the head of the file where you included the zoeken script.

Comment: I've added the script tags to the head, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML jquery.min.js is included twice - once from googleapis.com, and then again from your own server.

Your code in overige.js is not executed immediately - it is scheduled to run once the entire document is loaded.

Maybe the second inclusion resets the content of $ and then $.geocomplete() is no longer available?

Comment: This fixed my problem! It was indead overwriten by the second inclusion.
You sir, are a true hero! Thank you very much.
Enjoy your day!